# cast operators with defined constants

Tags: c, operator-precedence, typecast-operator

I have checked that cast operators work fine also with #defined constants, e.g.

```
#define SAMPLES 100
#define SAMP_TIME_MAX 51

int main()
{
    float f_samp = (double) SAMPLES / SAMP_TIME_MAX;
    printf("f_samp = %f",f_samp);
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. is it a good practice or is there any better way to obtain the same effect?
2. how are the precedence rules, e.g. in the example above does (double) has effect on SAMPLES or on (SAMPLES / SAMP_TIME_MAX)?

Comment: Remember that #defined constants are substituted by blind token (basically textual) replacement.  So the precedence rules are, whatever the rules say *after* you do that substitution.  As long as your #define is a single numeric constant, there's virtually nothing that can go wrong — so yes, your casts are perfectly fine.

Comment: ... and, for (2) the cast operator has higher precedence than the arithmetic operators and is applied to `SAMPLES`. But, then, because of the rules for "usual arithmetic conversion," `SAMP_TIME_MAX` will be converted to `double` before the division operation.

Comment: Once upon a time, if you had something like `#define EOF -1` you could have problems, so it was a good idea to protect yourself by instead using `#define EOF (-1)`.

Comment: If you have something like `#define A B+C`, though, you're definitely going to have problems.  A later invocation of `A*3` will expand to `B+C*3`, and will give an unexpected result.  And `(typename)A` expands to `(typename)B+C` which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you define something, all that really happens at a high level is that the preprocessor goes around and replaces the instance of the definition with the value. So your example of:

```
#define SAMPLES 100
#define SAMP_TIME_MAX 51

int main()
{
    float f_samp = (double) SAMPLES / SAMP_TIME_MAX;
    printf("f_samp = %f",f_samp);
    return 0;
}
```

Is really just equivalent to:

```
int main()
{
    float f_samp = (double) 100 / 51;
    printf("f_samp = %f",f_samp);
    return 0;
}
```

So yes, its fine to cast it to a double.
Also, you would want to cast to a float, or change f_samp to a double.